# For 2 matrices $A$ and $B$, does $A^2$ similar to $B^2$ imply $A$ is similar to $B$?

Tags: matrices, similar-matrices

My doubt is: if $A^2$ is similar to $B^2$, then $A$ is similar to $B$. Are the following steps correct?

$\implies B^2 = P^{-1}A^2P$

$\implies B^2B^{-1} = P^{-1}A^2PB^{-1} $

$\implies B=P^{-1}A^2PB^{-1}$

$\implies PB=PP^{-1}A^2PB^{-1}$

$\implies PBP^{-1}=A^2PB^{-1}P^{-1}$

I have proved if $A$ and $B$ are similar, $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are also similar. Therefore, $PB^{-1}P^{-1} = A^{-1}$

$\implies PBP^{-1}=A^2A^{-1}$
$\implies PBP^{-1}=A$

Hence, A and B are similar.

Edit: As mentioned below, this proof is incorrect because the matrices have to be invertible for $PB^{-1}P^{-1}=A^{-1}$ and I have assumed the matrices to be similar which is the thing we are trying to prove.

Regards

Comment: You've assumed $A$ and $B$ are invertible. Were you supposed to do that?

Comment: @CyclotomicField I know that similar matrices are square matrices of same order. Is it not necessary that they be invertible?

Comment: Similarity preserves invertibility so every matrix without an inverse has a similarity class that isn't invertible. You should prove this and find some $2 \times 2$ examples to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Consider $A=(1), B=(-1)$. Then $A^2=B^2=(1)$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a logical leap in your statement $A^2PB^{-1}P^{-1} = A^2A^{-1}$. Why would this be true.

What you are trying to prove is false, even assuming invertibility of $A$ and $B$. Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$.